# How to set a global session for the whole app in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, session, global

How can I set a global session in Laravel. In a normal PHP-script a global session like `$_SESSION['myvar']` dies if the browser is closed or the function `session_destroy()`/`unset()` is called.

I tried this in Laravel, but it does not work in a controller extends BaseController:

```
Session::set( 'id', $user->id );
Session::get( 'id' );
```

The Context of my code is:

```
// ROUTES
Route::get( '/', 'MyController@setSession' );


// CONTROLLER
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function setSession( )
    {
       // ...
    Session::set( 'id', $user->id );
    return view('access');  
    }
}


// VIEW -> LOST Session
@if (Session::has('id') && Session::get('id') == 'hsdiwe78912hj')
    I have access!
@else
    I must stay here! <!-- I always get this -->
@endif
```

Comment: Do you store the Session in the Database? Which Session Driver are you using? From where do you get the ID 'hsdiwe78912hj'? Does $user->id also return the User ID? Is the Sessions stored, whats the Output if you dd all Sessions with Session::all() ?

Comment: Laravel uses Service Providers to "configure"/set up the application before running any logic code. The session is configured in `config/session.php`, it's an important file (I mean: you cannot ask anything about session not working as expected without showing this file).

Comment: the idea of the session is to get terminated once the browser is closed, thats the whole idea behind the session, however if u need a more persistent solution, try the cache driver...if u still want to use the session driver make sure u import the session namespace in ur controller or whatever if u r using the v5 of laravel.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
Session::put('id', $user->id );
Session::get('id' );
Session::forget('id' );
```

Comment: how does this fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not properly defining `$user->id`. Try this:

```
Session::set( 'id', Auth::id() );
```

Comment: @mike-barwick I am under the impression that facades are going away. Why do you prefer to use facades?

Comment: Where you hearing that? lol I highly doubt Laravel is going to scrub Facades. There's a time and place to use them. In this case, esp with `Auth`, it's shorter and cleaner. Too each their own though of course.

Comment: More info on Facades from the man himself. http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/

Comment: @MikeBarwick I just checked and I wrongly characterized what I had read. My first version of Laravel was 5.1 (a few months ago) and I was interested in keeping pattern with my previous PHP experience, so I looked into Facades and found Taylor Otwell's blog post [Response: Don’t Use Facades](http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/). If you read it you can clearly see this is not a phase out. That being said I prefer to avoid Facades but appreciate that you edited my response to be more consistent with context of the question asked.

Comment: For sure! To each there own. I typically inject my dependancies, but some facades make sense and is easily/cleaner to read. Even many of the decency injections are formed from facades too - can never hide from them haha

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hints! I did not know, that Laravel does not use normal $_SESSION or session_start as like PHP uses.

The hint of yesterday: config/session.php has to be edited:

```
'expire_on_close' => true,  // expires when browser is closed
```